# Can I get bill-shocked by Linode?

Tags: vps, cloud-hosting, bandwidth, pricing, linode

I am looking at going with Linode for my cloud hosting needs. I want to start off cheap with their $10 plan. Looking at the 'fine print' I got alarmed by this:

> If you exceed your monthly bandwidth quota, your account will be billed for $0.02/GB at the end of the current month.

Making some quick calculations, I worked out that I *could* be billed for $6,479,999.96 (bandwidth overages over the 2TB quota at 125 Mbps).

Is this correct? Is there a way that I can prevent this for *sure*? I would rather no way to be charged over $10 than it be very very unlikely that I would be charged over $10.

Is there a way to auto-shutdown the Linode when I exceed my transfer quota?

Comment: 125 what? (capital B for Bytes)

Comment: @Jasen 125 megabits per second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way at this point to do that with Linode. Having used them a while back as a provider I believe they sent emails at the time to alert when usage approached 100% of the plan allowance so you could make the appropriate changes to reduce your costings but there is no way in advance to prevent the usage from going over without actually monitoring it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use VNstat to send you hourly reports via a cron, and then manually shut down your http server via a shell on your mobile device.